# Is any function proof of equality of its range and domain elements according to HoTT?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

According to [wikipedia article on HoTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory#Equality):

> In HoTT, the type a=b is the type of all paths from the point a to the point b. (Therefore, a proof that a point a equals a point b is the same thing as a path from the point a to the point b.)

Is path kind of a map here?
Does that mean that any function is the proof of equality between elements of its domain and range?

For example is $f(x)=3+x$ a proof of equality of 4 and 7?

Comment: No, a "path" in this sense is *just* a term of type $a=b$ in HoTT. Calling it a path is just an informal gloss coming from the idea of *interpreting* types as spaces.

Comment: @Malice Thanks for the comment. Then what would the points on the path between points a and b represent? Are they the steps of proof (e.g. $\beta -reduction$ steps)?

Comment: @Malice Also doesn't the existence of path between two points mean there is a bidirectional mapping between points a and b, an isomorphism, which makes the equivalent?

Comment: There are no "points on the path". The "path" is a basic datum not reducible to anything else. Types are not *literally* spaces, they simply have some formal behaviors that are *like* spaces (up to homotopy equivalence). I don't understand your second comment; what's a mapping between two terms of a type supposed to be?

Comment: @Malice Well if path is a solid object like what you said then my second question is irrelevant. But again according to HoTT, a path between points x and y is represented by a continues map $p:[0,1] \rightarrow X$, where p(0)=x and p(1)=y. Doesn't that mean although the path is continues but still it is made of points?

Comment: That is *not* what a path is according to HoTT, which I've already pointed out. That's what a path is in homotopy theory, a branch of topology which *motivates* aspects of HoTT. But once again, *in the type theory* "paths" are just terms of equality types, and types are *not actually spaces*. I really don't know how many more ways I can say this.

Comment: @Malice Take it easy Malice. I got it now. :) I really appreciate you making it clear to me :) thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help!